# Programmatically restore "use default value" setting for images

Tags: magento-1.7, api, product-images

How can I programmatically restore the `Use Default Value` option for store-view images as shown in the image below?

[image: a busy cat]

I would like to do this with PHP via the Magento API for a group of products in bulk.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?

Comment: We ended up writing a script which does some horrible stuff directly to the database to delete the attribute values. Not elegant!

Comment: Cheers for the response, appreciate it was a long time ago.  I know for attributes you can set the value to false - just trying a few things out.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the "false" option didn't seem to reset the attributes back to default once the store scope had been changed (as in attributes with different values for each store couldn't be reset back to default) - but I may be wrong.

Comment: Am just about to test:  $product->setStoreId($storeId)->setThumbnail(false)->save()

Comment: hmm works, but am using v1.9

Comment: Good to know - hopefully it was fixed in the newer version.